# LoadMovieclips Array Click Btn Array

Tags: actionscript-3

How can click on any button to load the array into the concrete contents of the array Teddy I Grateful (Load Movieclips Array Click button Array)
    var teddy:Array = [home,about,products,services,contact];
    var l:int = teddy.length;
    for (var j:int = 0; j < l; j++) {
    var mc1=new teddy[j];
    var mc2=new teddy[1];
    teddy[j].buttonMode = true;
    var Btn:Array = [Btnhome,Btnabout,Btnproducts,Btnservices,Btncontact];
    var W:int = Btn.length;
    for (var i:int = 0; i < W; i++) {
    var mc:MovieClip = new Btn[i];
    mc.buttonMode = true;
    mc.x=400+i*100;
    mc.y=600+i;
    mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
    addChild(mc);
    }
    }

```
function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
switch (event.currentTarget) {
case mc :
addChild(mc1);  
trace("home");
mc1.x=400;
mc1.y=200;
break;
case mc :
addChild(mc2);  
trace("about");
mc2.x=400
mc2.y=300
break;
case products_mc :
trace("products");
break;
case services_mc :
trace("services");
break;
case contact_mc :
trace("contact");
break;
}}
```

Comment: Your code isn't correctly formatted and your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I will try to help you one more time. But you must talk to the people trying to help you. If you dont understand just ask. Also at least **up-vote** useful answers to your questions or **mark as correct** if it works okay. Otherwise no-one wants to type tutorials (because there is Google and ActionScript manual for that).

The best way to test my shown code is... Make  a **new blank FLA file** and save to some folder. Now go to **Properties** (ctrl+F3) and in the **Class:** box type in there **Array_buttons_v1** (press enter and save FLA again). Now you can click the pencil icon next to **Class:** box to edit your Class document. You will replace that auto-code with mine shown below.. (in photo: **MyClass** becomes **Array_buttons_v1**)

[image: image borrowed from: Adobe.com]
*image borrowed from: Adobe.com*

You will also need 5 movieClips in your library (ctrl+L). That is one movieClip to use as button MC and then four other movieClips to be added on stage when you click. Each one in Library must be right-clicked and choose "properties" then in **Linkage** section tick **Export for Actionscript** and use the following name in **Class** box shown there..

1. one small MC as button use: **btn_MC** (later we make MC clickable just like a real button)
2. other four MCs to add when button clicked use: **MC1**, **MC2**, **MC3**, **MC4**

Now you can use the main Properties (crtl+F3) to click the pencil icon (see pencil in photo) and delete all that automatic code and paste this code there.. (try to understand what code is doing, not just copy+paste..). It makes four buttons from MC class name **btn_MC** into some array and then loads other four MCs to array then from Mc array can add to screen too. Hope it helps

```
package  
{
    //** You will need more IMPORTS as you use other Flash features (APIs)
    //** But these two is enough here.. check AS3 manual or tutorials for what to add 

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class Array_buttons_v1 extends MovieClip 
    {

        public var MC_Array:Array = []; //new array is empty
        public var Btn_Array:Array = []; 

        public var MC_0 : MC1 = new MC1();
        public var MC_1 : MC2 = new MC2();
        public var MC_2 : MC3 = new MC3();
        public var MC_3 : MC4 = new MC4();

        public var btn_0 : btn_MC = new btn_MC();
        public var btn_1 : btn_MC = new btn_MC();
        public var btn_2 : btn_MC = new btn_MC();
        public var btn_3 : btn_MC = new btn_MC();

        public var mClips_holder : MovieClip = new MovieClip;
        public var buttons_holder : MovieClip = new MovieClip;


        public function Array_buttons_v1() 
        {
            //** Update MC array.. items are counted from 0,1,2,3 (NOT 1,2,3,4)
            MC_Array = [ MC_0, MC_1, MC_2, MC_3 ]; //meaning array pos [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]
            stage.addChild( mClips_holder ); //will hold  
            mClips_holder.y = 70; //move down so its not blocking anything 

            //** Update Buttons array
            Btn_Array = [ btn_0, btn_1, btn_2, btn_3 ];

            stage.addChild( buttons_holder ); //put Button holder on stage
            //buttons_holder.addChild( Btn_Array [0] ); //put Buttons inside holder

            var insert_pos:int = 0; //will use as screen "adding position" for buttons 

            //** To add all in array.. we start from pos of 0 and count up to 3
            //** For every count number we do instructions inside { } until count finished  
            for (var arr_pos:int = 0; arr_pos <= 3; arr_pos++) //create some counter
            {
                trace("position inside the array is now : " + arr_pos);

                //** setup instance Names for movieClips inside the MC Array 
                //** later you can access each one by name using "getChildByName" as MC_1 or MC_2 etc..
                MC_Array[arr_pos].name = "MC_" + ( String(arr_pos) );   

                //** setup Buttons (names, clicked functions etc )..
                Btn_Array[arr_pos].name = "button_" + ( String(arr_pos) );                  
                Btn_Array[arr_pos].buttonMode = true; //make clickable before adding to screen
                Btn_Array[arr_pos].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button_Clicked);

                buttons_holder.addChildAt( Btn_Array [arr_pos], arr_pos ); //add to container

                buttons_holder.getChildAt(arr_pos).x = insert_pos; 
                trace("pos of btn is now : " + buttons_holder.getChildAt(arr_pos).x);

                //update the adding position amount
                insert_pos += 50; //add +50 pixels distance for next item

            } //end For loop

        }

        public function button_Clicked ( evt :MouseEvent ) : void
        {
            //** Use "evt" because it matches with above "evt:MouseEvent" for access  
            trace( "Button name: " + evt.currentTarget.name + " ..was clicked" );

            //** Now you can use IF statement to run another function(s)
            //if (evt.currentTarget.name == "button_0") { some_Test(); } 

            //** or Use SWITCH statement (better and easier) 
            switch (evt.currentTarget.name)
            {
            case "button_0" :
                                //mClips_holder.addChild(MC_0); //** can be done like this ..
                                mClips_holder.addChild( MC_Array[0] ); //but you wanted from array so do this way..
                                mClips_holder.getChildByName("MC_0").x = 0;

                                some_Test(); //to do some other function

                                //** to stop this button listening for mouse clicked
                                //Btn_Array[0].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button_Clicked);

                                break;

            case "button_1" :
                                mClips_holder.addChild(MC_1);  
                                mClips_holder.getChildByName("MC_1").x = 40;
                                //Btn_Array[1].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button_Clicked);
                                break;

            case "button_2" :
                                mClips_holder.addChild(MC_2);  
                                mClips_holder.getChildByName("MC_2").x = 80;
                                //Btn_Array[2].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button_Clicked);
                                break;

            case "button_3" :
                                mClips_holder.addChild(MC_3);  
                                mClips_holder.getChildByName("MC_3").x = 120;
                                break;

            } //end Switch/Case  

        }

        public function some_Test ( ) : void
        {
            trace(" ### This is some other function... do extra things in this section");

            //your extra code here..
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I was typing too quickly last time so I have updated a little bit to help you. Read again and re-paste this new code (small changes though, and maybe you understand enough to not even need this new edit but just in case... (PS: glad it was useful for you)

Answer (score 1):

if *[home,about,products,services,contact]*,
and *[Btnhome,Btnabout,Btnproducts,Btnservices,Btncontact]* are object *instance Name*'s, then your code is wrong.

But in that case, you can position them once, then each time set them visible/invisible with this;

```
// set as invisible
myArray[i].visible = false;
// set as visible
myArray[i].visible = true;
```

Else, if you have to re-create them each time, then you must specify an Object Class for your objects, and call them with their object classes

```
var mc = new myObjClass();
```

1. And to give object classes names that you can refer from your code, do the following;
2. In your *Library panel*,
3. Select the MovieClip you want to create instances of,
4. [Right-Click] > Properties...
5. Check *Export for ActionScript*
6. And give *Class* name below. Then use that class name in your code to create new MovieClip instances of it every time.

Depending on your Flash version that process can be slightly different. But you can google it anyway.

Hope that helps.